# Debit cards for android in-app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment

I have implemented the in-app billing api in my android app. But my users in India are unable to make the purchase with their debit card. I used my Indian debit card to purchase apps from Playstore 2yrs back and it worked fine.

1. Has Google Wallet stopped supporting Debit Cards in India?
   Or
2. Do we need to issue special type of International debit cards from the bank?

I know that credit card works... but my users dont have access to credit cards. My app is beginning to catch popularity now with about 500 users, and I am getting constant queries from people asking my why debit cards are not working to purchase within the app.
Is something that we can do to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: how would my app name help u solve my query?

Answer (score 0):

Credit and Debit cards both are supported. It is just matter of the debit card type. It is a matter of the supported debit card. As far as I know all the debit cards are not supported in Google wallet. I remember using ICICI debit card at least. Due to strict RBI rules on debit cards not all the banks are supporting google wallet linking.